# Visual Studio: New line at end of file on save

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

How do I configure Visual Studio to automatically add an empty line (if not exist) at the end of a file on save?

Comment: Visual studio code, or classic visual studio?

Comment: Visual Studio. It's certainly annoying when I try to Google this, and the only results I get are for VS Code!

Comment: Are you using a specific language, or is this a git issue where it was configured to save as `unix` style when checking in?

Comment: The context is me exploring Visual Studio as an alternative IDE for C# to Rider and VS Code, and I have created the most basic console app to test out the IDE.

Comment: You will have to do it the old-fashioned way, after opening up a file, add a blank line to the end. Unclear why you feel you need to do that in C#, I've been working in C# for 20+ years now and never had that need.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like the following to your `.editorconfig` file:

```
[*]
insert_final_newline = true
```

Comment: I added a `.editorconfig` file in the root directory that `Main.cs` resides in, with the 2 lines in your answer. Absolutely nothing happens to the file when I save, or when I `Format Document`. I am on Visual Studio 2022 for Mac.

Comment: The file should be in the root directory of your project/repository. But then, it should be picked up automatically. it may need a restart of VS, though.

Comment: It appears that the file gets picked up, as it picks up settings like `indent_size = n` for some number `n`. However, it doesn't pick up `insert_final_newline = true` for some reason. I verified on a text editor that no new line is added at the end of saved files.

Comment: It also doesn't handle `trim_trailing_whitespace` on Save either.  File a VS feedback for it, it helps the product team prioritize these issues.

Comment: I didn't test this particular entry, but I also saw some options working, others not. And I didn't find any diagnostic messages about it (e.g. error logs on _why_ some options don't work)